# Extend vector system to space basis

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Extend $\{x_1,x_2\}$ vector system to space basis,

if $x_1$ = $(1,2,3,4)$ and 
$x_2$ = $(2,1,0,1)$

Is there any chance that question is missing arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you are asked to choose two vectors which together wirh the given two form a basis of the 4dimensional real vector space